# ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nnet’

Tags: r, nnet, renv

I just updated R version to R 4.3.1. Together with the new R, I downloaded XQuartz-2.8.5.pkg and gfortran-12.2-universal.pkg.

In my project, the lockfile of my `renv` was generated with R 4.2.0. Initialising the project, it tells me:

```
- One or more packages recorded in the lockfile are not installed.
- Use `renv::status()` for more details.
```

I checked, and following the steps in `?renv::status()` it says: "If you have multiple packages in an inconsistent state, we recommend `renv::restore()`, then `renv::install()`, then `renv::snapshot()`, but that also suggests you should be running status more frequently."

After running `renv::restore()` I successfully downloaded all missing packages, but when installing I get an error with package "nnet".

```
Error: Error installing package 'nnet':
================================

* installing *source* package ‘nnet’ ...
** package ‘nnet’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
using C compiler: ‘Apple clang version 14.0.3 (clang-1403.0.22.14.1)’
using SDK: ‘MacOSX13.3.sdk’
clang -arch arm64 -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/opt/R/arm64/include    -fPIC  -falign-functions=64 -Wall -g -O2  -c nnet.c -o nnet.o
nnet.c:73:12: error: unknown type name 'Sint'; did you mean 'int'?
VR_set_net(Sint *n, Sint *nconn, Sint *conn,
           ^~~~
           int
[...]

18 errors generated.
make: *** [nnet.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘nnet’
* removing ‘/Users/estebanmenaresbarraza/Documents/BTU-PhD/troph-cost/renv/staging/1/nnet’
install of package 'nnet' failed [error code 1]
```

Could anybody help me please?

I'm running a Mac with Ventura 13.5 and Apple M1 Pro

Thanks!

I tried searching on the internet but got no results...

Also, when I tried to instal the package outside the project (in a empty project) I could install it with no problems, so it might be something with the `renv`?